# Mongodb: words disappeare from String filed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm facing a strange problem with mongodb database. In the following schema; i store in the field `instructions` a long text, and stragely sometimes i find that few words have disappeared from it.

```
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Title cannot be blank'
    },
    instructions: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
});
```

I'm sorry i dont have more details about the issue, so i need some suggestion or ideas that could help.

Thanks

UPDATE:
Here is an exemple:

The original value :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nulla pellentesque, consectetur velit pellentesque, consectetur dui. Nulla purus ante, eleifend vitae ornare ut, molestie quis metus. Nulla a augue ut orci fermentum blandit vel et elit. Pellentesque fermentum arcu erat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae posuere libero. Etiam non ex non risus ornare laoreet ac in tortor. Quisque malesuada tortor vulputate neque bibendum, bibendum vestibulum lacus cursus. Sed ac condimentum purus. Pellentesque nec tincidunt odio. Mauris ac tellus interdum, luctus augue et, cursus ex. Duis vulputate arcu at enim tincidunt, ut hendrerit mauris dapibus. Vivamus ullamcorper eu nisl et fringilla. Sed vel ornare sem. Proin porta erat sit amet nulla rhoncus tincidunt.

after few days (moment or whatever), i found:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nulla pellentesque, consectetur velit pellentesque, consectetur dui. Nulla purus ante, eleifend vitae ornare ut, molestie quis metus. Nulla a augue ut orci fermentum blandit vel et elit. Pellentesque fermentum arcu erat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae posuere libero. Etiam non ex non risus ornare laoreet ac in tortor. Quisque malesuada tortor vulputate neque bibendum, bibendum vestibulum lacus cursus. Sed ac condimentum purus. Pellentesque nec tincidunt odio. Mauris ac tellus interdum, luctus augue et, cursus ex. Duis vulputate arcu at enim tincidunt, ut hendrerit mauris dapibus. Vivamus ullamcorper eu nisl et fringilla. Sed vel ornare sem. Proin porta erat sit amet

Comment: Can you provide sample data? If it's not reproducible, the community will vote to close your question

Comment: i added an exemple, unfourtenty i dont have too much details about this issue, that why i wonder if someone knows what could cause this

Comment: Note: ... Proin porta erat sit amet **null**a rhoncus tincidunt. You need to check if there is any problem with `null` text inside your entries.